# Replace xpath element for a shorter one or a CSS selector selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

i am using Selenium and i would like to replace xpath to get a list of this

elements.

[image]

So far this xpath works, but i think is is unsophisticated. I think is better change for a CSSselector or shorter xpath, but i am not able to gat the same result.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: please add html as text and not as screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Below xpath will work

```
"//div[@id='igTreeProjectTree']//li[starts-with(@data-path, '0_0_')]"
```

Because I think data-path is unique in all elements

Answer (score 0):

For the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//*[@id='igTreeProjectTree']/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li
```

The equivalent [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) will be:

```
#igTreeProjectTree > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li
```

---

A more canonical [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) would be:

```
#igTreeProjectTree ul[data-depth='2'] > li.ui-igtree-node-nochildren[data-path='0_0_0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS-selector:

```
'#igTreeProjectTree li.ui-igtree-node-nochildren'
```